# SQL Parameter on c# context

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to add a parameter to this sql query  to be executed against an Entity Framework context. I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax. Here is what I have so far:

```
db.Participantes.SqlQuery("SELECT participanteID, nome, email, telefone, unidadeCE, voucherNumero, dataCadastro," +
                          "(SELECT TOP(1) tipo FROM ParticipanteResultado pr WHERE p.participanteID = pr.participanteID ORDER BY quantidadeValidas DESC) AS tipo" +
                          "FROM Participante p WHERE p.unidadeCE = @param", new { param = unidade }).ToList()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: What i meant is i don't know how to add the parameter, i know it must be a object but i never used this kind before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for as for as adding parameters to your EF query.

```
db.SqlQuery<TEntity>("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = @ParamName", 
               new SqlParameter("ParamName", parameterValue)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, that's exactly what i was looking for !

Just don't know why the down votes :/